# Finding the maximum proportions in sub groups

Tags: dplyr, group-by, summarize

I have a data set that I can share a small piece of it:

```
ID=c(1,1,2,3,3,1,2,4,2,1,2,1,4,3,1,2,3)
country=c("USA","Canada","Mexico","UK","UK","Mexico",
          "USA","Canada","Canada","Mexico","UK","Mexico","Canada","Canada",
          "USA","USA","UK")
sold_items=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)
df <- data.frame(ID,country,sold_items)
```

```
> df %>% sample_n(5)
  ID country sold_items
1  3      UK          0
2  1     USA          1
3  3      UK          0
4  2     USA          0
5  1  Canada          0
```

I was able to find the sales price for each country as follows:

```
df %>% group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(n_total=n(), per_total=round(n()/nrow(.),digits= 4)*100,
            sales_rate=sum(sold_items[sold_items==1])/n_total * 100)
```

```
 country n_total per_total sales_rate
1 Canada        5      29.4         80
2 Mexico        4      23.5         75
3 UK            4      23.5         25
4 USA           4      23.5         50
```

However I need to add 5 separate columns corresponding to each country to show the top 2 sales IDs in that country and the sales proportion of each top ID in that country,  For example, in `Canada` the `sales_rate`  is `80(%)` and I need to know how much is it by the  `top_ID_1 (%)` and how much by `top_ID_1 (%)`. Also, eventually, one column to aggregate the names of top IDs in each province.
So, my idea hypothetical data set would look like:

```
country   n_total   per_total     sales_rate  top_ID_1   top_ID_1 (%)   top_ID_2  top_ID_2(%)  names_top_IDs
1 Canada        5      29.4         80
2 Mexico        4      23.5         75
3 UK            4      23.5         25
4 USA           4      23.5         50
```

Comment: can you fill in what the data should look like for those columns in the hypothetical dataset? I don't really understand what your desired output should look like.  You might want to start by defining what you mean by Top 2 sales IDs.. What if there are ties, like there are in your sample dataset? (Look at Canada, looks like ID 4 is perhaps top #1 in terms of number of items sold by ID 2 and 3 are tied for top #2)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(
    n_total = n(), 
    per_total = round(n()/nrow(.),digits= 4)*100,
    sales_rate = sum(sold_items)/n_total * 100, 
    top_ID_1 = names(sort(table(ID), decreasing = TRUE)[1]), 
    top_ID_1_per = sum(sold_items[ID == top_ID_1]/n_total * 100)
  )
```

Although I don't think it will handle ties nicely...